# Using parameters.yml in Symonfy 3.3

Tags: symfony, global-variables, symfony-3.3

I still trying to know which way to use the parameters is the most logical and efficient way.

I realize that I can get the parameters from the parameters.yml in the Controller thanks to the "extends Controller" and "use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;" I added in the Controller file.

From this controller I instance a new User() from the file User.php in AppBundle\Model\User; that I created and looks like this:

```
namespace AppBundle\Model;

use \PDO;


class User
{

    private function open_database_connection()
    {
        $link = new PDO("mysql:host=database_host;dbname=database_name","database_user","database_password");
        return $link;
    }
    public function get_something_from_database()
    {

        $link = $this->open_database_connection();
        //query's execution, fetch, etc...
        ...
    }

    ...

}
```

At the moment as you can see I just write the parameters straight to the new PDO function to make the connection but I want to use the parameters from the parameters.yml file.

As I see, I could pass the connection's parameters from the controller creating an user object and passing to the function get_something_from_database($parametersConnection) by parameters and finally to the open_database_connection also by parameters.

My question is... exist any way to avoid to pass all the time the parameters of the connection from the controller to the model objects? Perhaps a way to get the parameters from the parameters.yml straight from inside the function open_database_connection or some other solution?

How you do it usually? Thank you for you help.

Comment: Do you intentionally not use doctrine? And even if, those methods on a user model really do look like bad practice. But that said, inject the parameters via a service or a factory.

Comment: Yes... I intentionally don't want to use Doctrine... I don't need Doctrine for what I'm working on. And I think is optional to use Doctrine...

Comment: It certainly is. Then have a factory/service which get's wired up via the service container, by this you can inject values from `parameters.yml` and in turn inject those into the model classes. Though I think a separate db-service being injected (in your case a simple instance of PDO) is certainly more appropriate.

Comment: Event you don't want to use doctrine, you can use it only to initialize the database connection and make raw sql queries through a connection  which is what you are actually doing.

Comment: So the question is... how you will do it without using Doctrine? could you give me an example? or give me a reference from some documentation? I can't get all you mean srry...

Comment: I'll try to write up a simple answer.

Comment: Cheers Yoshi... let's see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally I discovered how to use the connexion from Doctrine. I will expose what I will do. If you think I'm wrong please answer me again.

What I will do is, every time I need to play with the db I will send the connection by parameter to the instance of the model.

From Controller inside an action function:

```
$user = new User($this->container->get('database_connection'));
$something = $user->get_something_from_db_options();
```

From the last Model explained called User I will leave it like this:

```
namespace AppBundle\Model;

use \PDO;


class User
{
    private $connection;

    public function __construct($connection)
    {
        $this->connection = $connection;
    }

    public function get_something_from_database()
    {

       $result = $this->connection->query('SELECT * FROM users');
       ...
    }
...
}
```

I hope it's starting to looks better.

I'm trying to avoid the mapping and entitys concept from the Doctrine I just want to make the connection the rest of things about db I want to control them myself.

If you think I can clean more my code please don't stop saying me this.

Comment: Again, please don't add answers as follow-up questions. This is not how SO works. If you have questions about an answer write a comment, if you have a new question, post a new question. Also you got an answer regarding *how it can be done* any question regarding *should it be done this way* will likely be closed as *off topic* or *opinion based*.

Comment: yes srry... won't do it again... I didn't mean to do that...

Anyway... Do u think is my code now better? or still thinking I'm wrong. How u will do it?

Comment: No, I don't think you should do it like that. I think you should use doctrine, for your own sake and for anyone who might later inherit your code.

Comment: I'm using the Doctrine. Don't you see it? 
$this->container->get('database_connection') 
This is the connection from Doctrine. Are u trying to say me that I should use all the functions that provides Doctrine? As could be the entity's and mapping, etc? Well is not my intention... Beside that is all ok?

If there is any next developer. If knows how it works PHP and Symfony he/she won't have any problems... So... I repeat... I'm wrong?

Comment: You're not using *doctrine orm*, you're using [*doctrine dbal*](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/dbal.html). And yes, I'd advice to use doctrine fully (meaning orm) because I doubt you'll fare better re-implementing all the functionality doctrine already provides you with. For now you haven't explained why you don't want to use doctrine. That said, instead of injecting the connection into model classes, I'd at least have repository classes (mapped as services). Because in the end, it makes no sense to ask `User` to load another `User`.

Comment: Regarding the *next developer*. I think your argument is wrong. Knowing symfony and/or php alone, won't help with using whatever structure you come up. But knowing doctrine, and knowing that you're project uses doctrine, will instantly enable the next developer to understand and use your code (at least with regard to the database handling).

Comment: Well... I suppose here is when each developer choose what to learn more... For me is not difficult at all to read php and symfony things if they are commented.. even if they are not mine... honestly doctrine could be also difficult to understand but all people should know how it works php, symfony and mysql if they use symfony but not all the people should know how to use doctrine if they want to use symfony.
I like more the old school. It won't disappear. Doctrine... Not sure... At the moment at least I will continue like this. But thank you very much. It was really helpful your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To access the parameters.yml var, you have to be inside a Controller.
That way, you just have to make :

```
$this->getParameter('_param_name');
```

and send that value to the Entity.

Therefore if you look obviously, you'll see that **getParameter()** is a member function of **Controller** class :

```
namespace Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller;
abstract class **Controller** implements ContainerAwareInterface
```

so, you have to try this :

```
<?php
namespace AppBundle\Model;

use \PDO;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;


class User extends Controller
{

  private function open_database_connection()
  {

//    This
    $param_X = $this->getParameter('_param_');
//    Or this...
    $param_X = $this->container->get('_param_');


    $link = new PDO("mysql:host=database_host;dbname=database_name","database_user","database_password");
    $link = new PDO("mysql:host=database_host;dbname=database_name","database_user","database_password");
    return $link;
  }
  public function get_something_from_database()
  {

    $link = $this->open_database_connection();
    //query's execution, fetch, etc...
//    ...
  }

//...

}
```

But honestly, I don't think that's the way Symfony meant Entities to be...

Comment: Extending `Controller` does not automatically inject the service container. This only happens because `Controller` indirectly implements `ContainerAwareInterface` and this is checked while symfony creates the concrete instance of the controller object. The service container then get's injected via `ContainerAwareInterface::setContainer`.

Answer (score 0):

for multiple connections I recommend you define them in the config.yml and paramerter.yml files

parameter.yml

```
       database_host: hostdatabase1
        database_port: null
        database_name: userdatabase1
        database_user: preucv
        database_password: passwordatabase1
        database_host2: hostdatabase2
        database_port2: null
        database_name2: database2name
        database_user2: databaseuser2
        database_password2: databasepass2


config.yml 
Define de conecctions 
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                server_version:       5.6.44 
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8
                default_table_options:
                    charset:              utf8
                    collate:              utf8_general_ci
                mapping_types:
                    enum: string
                    set: string
                    varbinary: string
                    tinyblob: text

            database2:
                server_version:       5.6.44 
                host:     "%database_host2%"
                port:     "%database_port2%"
                dbname:   "%database_name2%"
                user:     "%database_user2%"
                password: "%database_password2%"
                charset:  UTF8
                default_table_options:
                    charset:              utf8
                    collate:              utf8_general_ci
                mapping_types:
                    enum: string
                    set: string
                    varbinary: string
                    tinyblob: text


and define the mapping 

  orm:
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    YourEntitiesDatabase1Bundle:  ~



           database2:
                connection:database2
                mappings:
                    YourEntititiesDatabase2Bundle:  ~
```

In the controller call de connection

```
$em   = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager('database2'); 
 $em   = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager('default');
```

or